# Open File, then read file and make them no line

Tags: python, lines

```
numbers = []

dataFile = open("numbers.txt")

for inputLine in dataFile:
    elements = inputLine.split()
    numbers1 = elements[0]
    print(numbers1)
```

My text File looks like this:

```
45
6
9
10
11
```

I am trying to make it to read like this, [45,6,9,10,11]
So I can do the sorting process, which I know how to do the sorting, but this one, I have trouble with it. I have tried many possibility ways to make it to one line, instead of 5 lines. I tried to do strip(), it doesn't came out well.

EDIT:

```
elements = []

dataFile = open("numbers.txt")

for inputLine in dataFile:
    elements = [int(line) for line in dataFile]
    print(elements)
```

This problem, 
My text File looks like this:

```
45
6
9
10
11
```

when I did that, it's missing 45. Everytime, it is taking first number away.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use a nested loop, the outer `for inputLine in dataFile:` will read the first line so the inner list comprehension `[int(line) for line in dataFile]` starts at `6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
   nums = [int(line) for line in f]
   nums.sort()
   print nums
```

**Output:**

```
[6, 9, 10, 11, 45]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great! When I did that, it is missing one number, which is the first one.

Comment: @user1552400 That is not possible.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. So is the for loop affecting the first number?

Comment: @user1552400 I already [did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199401/open-file-then-read-file-and-make-them-no-line/19199425?noredirect=1#comment28409730_19199401).

Comment: Yes you did point out the 'with'. So 'for' loop is impossible?

Comment: @user1552400 Did you read my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199401/open-file-then-read-file-and-make-them-no-line/19199425?noredirect=1#comment28409730_19199401) below your question? Using a nested loop here makes no sense, just remove the outer loop.

Comment: Oh I did not see it. Sorry. I looked here. my fault.

Comment: @user1552400 And it's a [good practice](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to use `with statement` for handling files, so do use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to list comprehension is using numpy, [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) is an easy way to load .txt, then you can sort the arrays with [`numpy.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.loadtxt('numbers.txt')
>>> print x
 [ 45.   6.   9.  10.  11.]
>>> np.sort(x)
 [  6.   9.  10.  11.  45.]
```

Comment: I cannot find the numpy in the Python Documentation.

Comment: Numpy is an extension to Python, install it with `pip install numpy`. It is the a fundamental package for scientific computing. If you are working with vectors, matrices, or perform any mathematical operation with them, you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print(numbers1),` (with the comma at the end) instead of just `print(numbers1)` to get it to print all on one line.